# Getting origin key to automatically populate foreign key while using relationship class in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, annotation, relationship-class, origin-destination

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop, and I am attempting to create feature linked annotations for my cable system and I have set up a relationship between the two features so that any changes made to the cables will automatically be updated in the annotation.

The cable feature's "GUID" field is set as the origin and I have created a "CableGUID" field in the annotation feature acting as the foreign key.

I can select a cable and choose to "Annotate Selected Features" which will generated the annotation but the origin key is not being migrated to the foreign key column.

Am I missing something with the set up?

[image]

Comment: What are the precise steps (tools and parameters) that you have performed to get you to where you are stuck?

Comment: Using ArcCatalog to create a new relationship in the dataset. This will be a 1-M, Composite relationship.

Comment: I think that information would be more useful as an [edit] to your question because potential answerers do not always read the comments on a question.

Comment: With no answers offered in over 18 months I think it is time for you to revise your question if you still need it answered.